# display text during IBAction in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some code as shown below:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    statusText.text = @"Processing...";

    //here I do a bunch of calculations

    //display calculated data
    statusText.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"coefficient: %.4f",
         [[coefficientEstimatesR objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];
}
```

The calculations that I do take about 17s, so I'd like to display the word "processing" while this is being done. However, when I run this, "processing" is never displayed, only the calculated data is displayed.

Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not do any processing in the GUI thread, not when it takes one second, and especially not when it takes 17 seconds. Using GCD makes offloading the task trivial:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    statusText.text = @"Processing...";

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        //here I do a bunch of calculations

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //display calculated data
            statusText.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"coefficient: %.4f",
                               [[coefficientEstimatesR objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work inside a while loop? I have been trying with no success. (I want to run the calculations indefinitely as we are trying to see how many times we can run this app before the ipad/ipod dies, this is for research purposes, and I need to print both the number of iterations so far completed and the calculated coefficient each time through the while loop).

Comment: See that inner call to dispatch_async()? You can do that anytime you want to update the status from your calculation code. You'd do well to read up on GCD -- very easy to use once you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I run this, "processing" is never displayed, only the
>   calculated data is displayed.

That's because drawing happens on the main thread. If you tie up the main thread doing your calculations, you'll block everything else that should be happening including drawing the status text.

Instead, set your status text, fire off a background thread (or dispatch a block to a queue, etc.), and return from your action method as quickly as you can. Have the background thread (or block) call a method on the main thread when the calculation is done so that you can change the status text again.